# SQLite udate with alias

Tags: sql, sqlite

I´m trying to make this update in SQLite:

```
UPDATE T_INPUT c SET (c.STATUS = 0, c.ERRORMSG='') where not c.ID in (SELECT a.ID FROM T_INPUT a, T_OUTPUT b where a.ID = b.FK_INPUT AND a.STATUS = 1)
```

When I run, my return is:

```
[System.Data.SQLite] ErrorCode: 1
ErrorMessage: SQL logic error or missing database
near "c": syntax error
```

But why? There´s nothing wrong here.

I tryed to use T_INPUT.ID instead of "c" but it didn´t work either.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try `UPDATE T_INPUT c SET STATUS = 0, ERRORMSG='' where ...`

Comment: Same error actually.. =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE T_INPUT c SET (...)
```

SQLite does not appear to support that table alias or (parens around SET values) in UPDATE statements. [See their official syntax documentation.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html)

If I alter your query like this, I get at least as far as SQLite complaining the table doesn't exist:

```
UPDATE T_INPUT 
SET 
    STATUS = 0, 
    ERRORMSG='' 
where T_INPUT.ID in (
    SELECT a.ID 
    FROM T_INPUT a, 
    T_OUTPUT b 
    where a.ID = b.FK_INPUT 
    AND a.STATUS = 1
);
```

Result: `Error: no such table: T_INPUT`

Hard to say more without seeing more, such as a database schema or SQL Fiddle example.

Comment: Thank you very much rutter.. I really don´t know why my query wasn´t working. I removed parens but the error persisted. I used the one that you wrote and it worked oO (feeling dumb hahaha) thank you thank you!! Guess it was c.STATUS and c.ERRORMSG

Comment: Sounds like. Glad I could help!